Asymptotics of Jacobi form
What are the large $x\in\mathbb R$ asymptotics of $f(x)=\theta_3(c_1+c_2 x^3,e^{-x^2})$ where $c_1,c_2$ are a pair of complex numbers (say, $\Re(c_2)>0$ and $\Im(c_2)<0$), and $\theta_3(a,b)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty b^{j^2}\cos(2ja)$ is the third Jacobi modular form?
The obvious approach doesn't seem to work and google is not helping. Numerically, it seems that $f(x)\sim e^{i p(x)}e^{\Im(c)^2x^4}q(x)$ where $p,q\in\mathbb R$, with $0<q<1$ a slowly varying function.
